# jPlayer playlist title element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I have seen similar questions, but no solutions.
I have jPlayer working beautifully except for one thing...
In "playlist" mode, the title element is set to `display:none`.
Is there a setting in the constructor to override this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use a jQuery listener and add the title programmatically as it plays...

```
$("#music").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event)
{
    $.each(player.playlist, function(index, song)
    {
        if(index == player.current)
        {
            $(".songTitle").html(song.title);
        }
    });
});
```

Where #music is the div you initally attach jplayer too and .songTitle is the class of the element where you want the title displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the css to show the title item by adding "important" like this:

```
div.jp-details {
    display: block !important;
}
```